# Best practice to apply rxjava in android app

Tags: android, system.reactive, mvp, clean-architecture

I am working currently on app where I want to apply some new practices,  architecture solutions and libraries (Rxjava, MVP, clean architecture). 
There is a login  process which consists from several steps:

1. Checking whether user account exist in local database on device
   if not nr.2 is executed
2. Request to server with email and id ( given by Google SignIn) - server checks if user already exists on remote server database
   a. if not - server sends error response (404)

   - base on the response I add new user  to server database
     if succeed
   - I save user to local database on device
     b. if exist (look on number 2)
   - I only save user to local database on device

Every single call is done with use of RXJava. 
Every call is based on the result from the previous one (base on response which is handled in subscriber). Every new call starts from the subscriber. 
If in subscriber is called OnError method I execute api call which save data on the server. All subscription to observable takes place in "presenter".

I am wondering whether is not possible to combine all this call in one (zip, flatmap) ? 
Any better idea?

Comment: You can take a look at this sample project http://github.com/mmirhoseini/marvel and this 5-part article https://hackernoon.com/yet-another-mvp-article-part-1-lets-get-to-know-the-project-d3fd553b3e21 to get more familiar with best practices of MVP, RxJava and etc.